# how to use 'linkedresource'

Tags: eclipse, gradle

here a eclipse project using 'link resource'  . but how to config in build.gradle. this is my config , but when i run 'gradle build'. there always are 'class not found' error. why? how to fix it.

`eclipse {
    wtp {
        facet {
            facet name: 'jst.java', version: '1.7'
            facet name: 'jst.web', version: '3.0'
        }
    }
    project {
        linkedResource name: 'zm_common', type: '2', location: 'D:/workspace/zm_common/src'
        linkedResource name: 'zm_common_resources', type: '2', location: 'D:/workspace/zm_common/resources'
    }
    classpath {
        file {
            withXml {
                def node = it.asNode()
                node.appendNode('classpathentry', [kind: 'src', path: 'zm_common', exported: true])
                node.appendNode('classpathentry', [kind: 'src', path: 'zm_common_resources', exported: true])
            }
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Any solutions you found?

Comment: I think I can make a 'linkedresource' jar . then copy it to my project . but it not very good! Is there any better solution with you ?